# NetworkX: how to build an Erdos-Renyi graph from a set of predetermined positions?

Tags: python, algorithm, random, graph, networkx

I need to build something like an Erdos-Renyi model (random graph):

[image]

I need to create it from a dictionary of node positions that is generated by a *deterministic* function. This means that I cannot allow Python to randomly decide where each node goes to, as I want to decide it. The function is:

`pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )`.

I was thinking of creating an *adjacency matrix* first, in order to randomly generate something similar to pairs of *(start, endpoint)* of each edge, like this:

`G=np.random.randint(0, 1, 25).reshape(5, 5)`

Then I was thinking of somehow turning the matrix into my list of edges, like this:

`G1=nx.grid_2d_graph(G)`

but of course it does not work since this function takes 2 args and I am only giving it 1.

**My questions:**

1. How to create this kind of graph in `NetworkX`?
2. How to make sure that all nodes are connected?
3. How to make sure that, upon assigning the `1` in the matrix, each pair of nodes has the same *probability* of landing a `1`?

**Example for point 3.** Imagine we created the regular grid of points which positions are determined according to `pos`. When we start connecting the network and we select the first node, we want to make sure that the *endpoint* of this first edge is one of the `N-1` nodes left in the network (except the starting node itself). Anyhow, we want to make sure that all `N-1` nodes have the *same probability* of being connected to the node we first analyze.

**Thanks a lot!**

Comment: 1) Create an Erdős-Rényi graph using `nx.erdos_renyi_graph`. Then assign node positions using the `pos` keyword argument when you plot. 2) You cannot ensure that all nodes are connected within an Erdős-Rényi random graph model, short of setting `p = 1`. 3) Again, this is not an ER graph model. In an ER model, there is a single probability `p` for connecting any pair of nodes.

Comment: @jme OK, let's say that this is not an ER model but rather a random graph with fixed positions. How could point 2 and 3 be accomplished?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "random graph with fixed positions". First, a graph and the positions of its nodes in a drawing are independent. You can sample from a random graph model and then assign node positions in a deterministic manner -- I don't see what the problem is here. Second, in order to answer (2) and (3), you need to more precisely specify your random graph model. One way to generate a random connected graph is to sample edges until the graph is connected. This may not meet the criteria of your application, though, so it's up to you to model your graph generation process.

Comment: To clarify my last point: You can generate a random connected graph by randomly choosing two nodes and flipping a coin to decide whether to connect them. You repeat the process until the graph is fully connected (which will happen with probability 1). But notice that this is not a uniform distribution over connected graphs! The graph you created necessarily has a cut of weight 1 -- the last step joins two sets by a single edge. But the fully-connected graph (with more than 2 nodes) admits no such cut. That is, this procedure cannot generate the fully connected graph.

Comment: I tried to create the graph with `G=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100,0.2)`, and then to assign `pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )` but it throws out: `IndexError: too many indices for array `. I wonder if the problem is in `pos`...

Comment: Well for one, `dict((n, n) for n in G)` won't be a valid position map. A position map should take a node to a 2-tuple of `(x, y)`-coordinates. The `dict` you've created maps a node to a single coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to build on the previous questions concerning this problem to be consistent. Given that you have the keys of the grid_2d_graph as 'n' and not (i,j) with the relabel nodes function:

```
N = 10
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() ) 
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
```

now you can set the pos dictionary to map from the 'n' keyed nodes to the positions you already have by switching keys with values. And then simply call the Erdos-Renyi function to create the graph that has a probability 'p' that an edge exists between any two nodes (except a self edge) as you described in **point 3**. Then draw with the pos dictionary.

```
pos = {y:x for x,y in labels.iteritems()}
G2 = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100,0.1)
nx.draw_networkx(G2, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 300)
print G.nodes()
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**As for ensuring that the graph is connected in point 2** You can not guarantee that the graph is connected with a probability 1, but you can read a bit about the size of the Giant component in Erdos-Renyi graph. But to avoid getting into theoretical details, one is almost sure that the graph will be connected when lambda which is n*p (here they are 100*0.1) is greater than 4. Though for smaller graphs (like 100 nodes) you better increase lambda. From my own experience using n= 100 and p = 0.1, produced a non-connected graph for only about 0.2% of the times and that is after thousands of simulations. And anyway you can always make sure if the produced graph is connected or not with the [is_connected](http://then%20you%20have%20the%20pos%20dictionary%20for%20the%20positions%20for%20the%20new%20labels%20as%20follows) method.

Comment: Thanks, great news! This is a *non-planar* (e.g., there are *edge-crossings*) graph but might serve the cause pretty well.